# Android is disallowing execution of native library when running as system app

Tags: android, android-ndk, selinux

When I sign my app with the system certificate, I can no longer use an SDK that comes with a custom native library. The SDK executes code from that native library. All works fine when my app is not signed as a system app, but when signed, I get an error.

The error appears to come from an SELinux policy with this log message:

> type=1400 audit(0.0:22): avc: denied { execute } for
>   comm=4173796E635461736B202331
>   path="/data/data/myapp/cache/librs.bitmap_to_argb.so" dev="mmcblk0p22"
>   ino=16791 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0
>   tcontext=u:object_r:system_app_data_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

Why would my app not be able to execute a library like this that is located in the app's internal storage?

Answer (score 0):

System apps expect their native libraries to be in /system/lib or lib64 directory. Maybe you can avoid this if you set **android:extractNativeLibs="false"** in the application manifest.

Comment: I tried adding that, but it didn't change anything. Using the default Android Studio build and run process, it results in "INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-2". If I build a signed apk, then install it with adb, it installs fine, but runs into the same error as posted.

Comment: Invalid APK? True, not all Android versions support android:extractNativeLibs="false". That's why I wrote 'maybe'.

Comment: If this app should go into /system/priv-app, try to manually copy the native libraries to /system/priv-app/your-app-name/lib

Comment: It's not a priv-app, just signed with the system certificate. The only solution I can think of now is to update the OS's SELinux policy, like in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47043397/2565692